# How do you create a local calendar?

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, eventkit

I'm trying to create a new iOS local calendar to store events related to my application. The reason for this instead of just storing the EventIdentifiers is because this application can sync between multiple devices. Since the EventIdentifier is read only... that won't sync up very well.

I'm doing this:

```
EKCalendar ticklerCalendar = new EKCalendar () { Title = "ClientTickler" };
```

It needs one of 3 overloads passed into the constructor... but, I have no idea how to form the objects it needs passed in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by the *3 overloads* you mean:

```
public EKCalendar (IntPtr handle);
public EKCalendar (NSObjectFlag t);
public EKCalendar (NSCoder coder);
```

then those are **not** what you're looking for. They are mostly used for interop with native code or for inheritance.

What you can use use is the static method `EKCalendar.Create`. You give it a `EKEntityType` type (`Event` or `Reminder`) and a `EKEventStore` store. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3924128/220643) has the Objective-C to do so.

Comment: Do I have to do Objective-C? Those where the 3 overloads definitely. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @BRogers, no you don't have to do Obj-C but you should be able to convert it to C# relatively easy since all the method/properties are named the same.

Comment: @poupou Thank you! I'm very happy with your answer. I'm relatively new to iOS development, and so far very happy with Xamarin. I think it would be beneficial to learn obj-c, but I can't currently justify the time. Thanks again!